# Index Error , works for 1D array

Tags: python, csv, numpy

```
from sklearn import tree
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer

data = np.genfromtxt('bank_int.csv', delimiter = '  ') 

sample = np.genfromtxt('test_sample.csv', delimiter = ' ') 

output = []
count = 0

train_data = data[:,:-1]
target_data = data[:,-1:]

decision_tree = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()           #creation of decision tree
decision_tree = decision_tree.fit(train_data, target_data)  #training the tree

for test in data:
    output[count] = decision_tree.predict(sample)       #testing the results
    count += 1

#result = decision_tree.predict(sample)

print output[count]
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "classification.py", line 21, in <module>
    output[count] = decision_tree.predict(sample)  #testing the results
IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Comment: error shown is as above

Comment: output is an empty list `output = []` so you cannot access elements that do not exist

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow. Please revise the "[how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)" paragraph in the stackoverflow guides.

Now, the problem you're experiencing is because you think in terms of a different programming language, possibly C. The error `IndexError: list assignment index out of range` shows that you're indexing an element that does not exist.

Instead of

```
for test in data:
    output[count] = decision_tree.predict(sample)       #testing the results
    count += 1
```

try:

```
for test in data:
    output.append(decision_tree.predict(sample))        #testing the results
```